# Is there a method that's called when an object is de serialized?

Tags: c#

I am trying to serialize an object, but HttpClient is causing problems. I can not serialize HttpClient - and personally I wouldn't want to - but when the object is de serialized, I need to ensure a HttpClient is available to make requests.

Is there a method that is called when an object is de serialized so I can ensure I create the HttpClient object and it's available for use?

Below is an example. The idea is that a user saves the session, and the serialized file is saved to disk. When the user loads the file, the cookieJar will restore the users Twitter session meaning they don't have to log back in (if the cookie session is still alive). I could just store the CookieCollection but, there's other data in the object that I need stored too. Hence why I am going about it this way.

```
[serializable()]
public class Twitter
{
    private HttpClient client;
    private CookieContainer cookieJar;

    private String username, password;

    public Twitter(string _username, string _password)
    {
        username = _username;
        password = _password;
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpClient & CookieContainer? Should really be looking in to using the OAuth and just storing the token.

Comment: @BradChristie I am not using Twitter ... that was just an example bud.

Comment: This depends very much on "which serializer". If that is `BinaryFormatter`, then the first thing that leaps to my mind is "stop using `BinaryFormatter`" (IMHO)

Comment: @MarcGravell I am using BinaryFormatter. What is the alternative?

Comment: @JamesJeffery: In that case I would probably abstract the auth information in to an `IAccount` (serializable) and reference that in a wrapper that uses HttpClient/CookieCOntainer

Comment: @JamesJeffery `DataContractSerializer`, `XmlSerializer`, `JavascriptSerializer`, Json.NET, protobuf-net, ServiceStack.Text, Thrift, ICE / ZeroC... need I go on?

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell I will check out DataContractSerializer or XmlSerializer.

Comment: @JamesJeffery note: `XmlSerializer` does not support serialization callbacks; `DataContractSerializer` *does* (via `[OnDeserialized]` in particular - see [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx)), as does protobuf-net.

Comment: @JamesJeffery I use DataContractSerializer, but be aware that it DOESN'T call the constructors of the class being deserialized.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question: [`IDeserializationCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.aspx) is there for this purpose.

```
[Serializable]
public class Twitter : IDeserializationCallback
{
    #region IDeserializationCallback

    void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(Object sender)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [`[OnDeserialized]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx):

```
[Serializable]
public class Twitter
{
    [OnDeserialized]
    void OnDeserialized(Object sender)
    {
    }
}
```

As an aside, I would look in applying [`[NonSerialized]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) to the HttpClient & CookieContainer and spin those up in a default ctor.

Comment: I need to serialize CookieContainer so the session can be stored and retrieved when the object is de serialized. Unless there's an alternative. As stated in other comment, Twitter was just an example OAuth is not available for the service I am using.

Comment: @JamesJeffery: Well, _techincally_ `CookieContainer` is Serializable so you should be safe, but I'd probably break your perpetual information out in to another storable medium.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a DTO to serialize and load the data from disk.

```
public class TwitterData
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EncryptedPassword { get; set; }
    public string SessionKey { get; set; }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can reconstruct the `Twitter` class from the DTO.

Comment: Data transfer object like the example I gave. It does not contain behavior or state which lends itself to serialization and interchange.